# Thumbnails dont show the correct image in Jquery

Tags: jquery, image, gallery, thumbnails

I have a problem creating a photo gallery for a website. Every thumbnail of the gallery show the image of the first thumbnail. The code I use:

```
    $(".thumb").click(function() {
    $(".image").fadeOut(500, function() {
        $(".image").attr("src",$(".thumb").attr("href"));
    }).fadeIn(500);
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're selecting the first image and thumnbnail in your javascript.  Use `$(this)` as a reference to the selected element, like this...

```
$(".thumb").click(function() {
    var $thumb = $(this);
    $(".image").fadeOut(500, function() {
        $(this).attr("src",$thumb.attr("href"));
    }).fadeIn(500);
    return false;
});
```

`$thumb` is the clicked element, and `$(this)` in the fadeOut callback is the selected image element.  I suspect that there's only 1 with the class `image`, but it's a further example of the use of `$(this)`.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using `$(".thumb").attr("href")` which will return the value of the first element matching that selector.